# Writing a pytest function for checking the output on console (stdout)

Tags: python, printing, stdout, pytest

[This Article](http://pytest.org/capture.html) describes how to use pytest for capturing console outputs. I tried the following code, but I get an error

```
import sys
import pytest
def f(name):
    print "hello "+ name

def test_add(capsys):
    f("Tom")
    out,err=capsys.readouterr()
    assert out=="hello Tom"


test_add(sys.stdout)
```

Output:

```
python test_pytest.py 
hello Tom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pytest.py", line 12, in <module>
    test_add(sys.stdout)
  File "test_pytest.py", line 8, in test_add
    out,err=capsys.readouterr()
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'readouterr'
```

I have also tried to replace `capsys` with `capfd`, but get the same error.

What is wrong and how can it be fixed?

Comment: brilliant, perfectly clear example

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `capfd` fixture.

**Example:**

```
def test_foo(capfd):
    foo()  # Writes "Hello World!" to stdout
    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    assert out == "Hello World!"
```

See: http://pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html for more details

And see: `py.test --fixtures` for a list of builtin fixtures.

Your example has a few problems. Here is a corrected version:

```
def f(name):
    print("hello " + name)


def test_f(capfd):
    f("Tom")

    out, err = capfd.readouterr()
    assert out == "hello Tom\n"
```

**Note:**

- Do not use `sys.stdout` -- Use the `capfd` fixture as-is as provided by pytest.
- Run the test with: `py.test foo.py`

**Test Run Output:**

```
$ py.test foo.py
====================================================================== test session starts ======================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.5 -- pytest-2.4.2
plugins: flakes, cache, pep8, cov
collected 1 items 

foo.py .

=================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ====================================================================
```

**Also Note:**

- You do not need to run your *Test Function(s)* in your test modules. `py.test` (*The CLI tool and Test Runner*) does this for you.

py.test does mainly three things:

1. Collect your tests
2. Run your tests
3. Display statistics and possibly errors

By default `py.test` looks for (*configurable iirc*) `test_foo.py` test modules and `test_foo()` test functions in your test modules.

Comment: this did not help. I get same error message. I pasted the code above for your reference

Comment: What version of pytest are you using? Try upgrading. This works as expected and shown in all my unit tests.

Comment: you never call this function `test_f(capfd)` in your code, is that ok?

Comment: The test runner and cli tool ``py.test`` does this for you. It does three things (*mainly*): 1) collect all your tests 2) run all your tests and 3) produces statistics and error output

Comment: how does it know which function to run for test? all functions with test_xxx?

Comment: Correct. THis is configrable IRRC but by default looks for ``test_foo.py`` modules and ``test_foo()`` function in those test modules.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is with your explicit call of your test function at the very end of your first code snippet block:

```
test_add(sys.stdout)
```

You should not do this; it is pytest's job to call your test functions.
When it does, it will recognize the name `capsys` (or `capfd`, for that matter)
and automatically provide a suitable pytest-internal object for you as a call argument.
(The [example given in the pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function) is quite complete as it is.)

That object will provide the required `readouterr()` function.
`sys.stdout` does not have that function, which is why your program fails.