# writing a pytest function to check outputting to a file in python?

Tags: python, function, file-io, pytest

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507601/writing-a-pytest-function-for-checking-the-output-on-console-stdout-in-python) question about how to write a pytest to check output in `stdout` and got a solution. Now I need to write a `test case`, to check if the contents are written to the file and that the contents are written as expected
eg:

```
def writetoafile():
   file = open("output.txt",w)
   file.write("hello\n")
   file.write("world\n")
   file.close()
```

now a pytest function to check if it written:

```
def test_writeToFile():
    file = open("ouput.txt",'r')
    expected = "hello\nworld\n"
    assert expected==file.read()
```

while this seems to work, I do not think this is ideal, especially hard-coding. how are these kind of `test functions` of writing to a file usually written?

Comment: Why would this not be ideal? You wrote you want to check the contents are written as expected, so looking into the file and checking seems the best option. You could always make a variable with a series of random characters and check if it was written successfully; you could check "expected in file.read()" to see if the data was appended (but you used flag 'w' so that's a bad test here); etc. What do you want to test for if not this? Perhaps knowing what you want is the real question here, as in most tests.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is the [tmpdir fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html) which will create you a per-test temporary directory.  So a test would look something like this:

```
def writetoafile(fname):
    with open(fname, 'w') as fp:
        fp.write('Hello\n')

def test_writetofile(tmpdir):
    file = tmpdir.join('output.txt')
    writetoafile(file.strpath)  # or use str(file)
    assert file.read() == 'Hello\n'
```

Here you're refactoring the code to not be hardcoded either, which is a prime example of how testing your code makes you design it better.

Comment: what does tmpdir does? so it creates a file virtually in memory?

Comment: It creates a real directory which you can inspect afterwards, on UNIX you'll typically find them in `/tmp/pytest-xxxx` with symlinks to the latest run.  You can always learn about fixtures by invoking `py.test --fixtures` and for the tmpdir case please refer to http://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html for more details.

Comment: pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: The link to the docs is a 404. You should always paste the docs directly in your answer.

Comment: Extracted from the docs : You can use the tmpdir fixture which will provide a temporary directory unique to the test invocation, created in the base temporary directory.

tmpdir is a py.path.local object which offers os.path methods and more. Here is an example test usage:
`def test_create_file(tmpdir): p = tmpdir.mkdir("sub").join("hello.txt")`

Comment: Updated the docs link again, note that these days you'd probably use `tmp_path` rather than `tmpdir`.  I think the answer already contains examples of how to use the api so not really sure what you mean with copying docs.

Answer (score 21):

Suppose you have this "amazing" piece of software in a file called `main.py`:

```py
"""
main.py
"""

def write_to_file(text):
    with open("output.txt", "w") as h:
        h.write(text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    write_to_file("Every great dream begins with a dreamer.")
```

To test the `write_to_file` method, you can write something like this in a file in the same folder called `test_main.py`:

```py
"""
test_main.py
"""
from unittest.mock import patch, mock_open

import main


def test_do_stuff_with_file():
    open_mock = mock_open()
    with patch("main.open", open_mock, create=True):
        main.write_to_file("test-data")

    open_mock.assert_called_with("output.txt", "w")
    open_mock.return_value.write.assert_called_once_with("test-data")
```

I always try to avoid writing files to disk, even if it's a temporary folder dedicated to my tests: not actually touching the disk makes your tests much faster, especially if you interact with files a lot in your code.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it's very helpful to mention mocking here. Here's an amazing article on testing (including DoubleTests like mocks): https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html

Comment: This should be the correct answer. Always avoid writing/reading to/from the disk in tests. Although it may be more "wordy", the test will run faster and does more to isolate what is being tested than the answer provided by flub

Comment: This is super helpful! The one change I needed to make to get it to work for me was swapping "main.open" to "builtins.open" in the call to `patch(...)`

Comment: I wouldn't say 'always' avoid doing anything.  There are times when you want to assert that your code is actually handling the file system the way you think it is.

Comment: Could you provide the same code using the `pytest` library, please? Thanks.

Comment: @blunova: the above works "as is" also with `pytest`: after the usual `pip install pytest`, just run `pytest` and the test file will be automatically discovered and run.