# Creating a temporary directory in PyTest

Tags: python, pytest

My Python project imports `pytest` 2.9.0 fine without any issues.

I want to create a new empty directory that will last only the life of the test session. I see that pytest offers temporary directory support:

https://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html

> You can use the tmpdir fixture which will provide a temporary directory unique to the test invocation, created in the base temporary directory.
>
> tmpdir is a py.path.local object which offers os.path methods and more. Here is an example test usage:

The source-code for pytest shows that `def tmpdir` is a global/module function: https://pytest.org/latest/_modules/_pytest/tmpdir.html

However my test file fails:

```
import pytest

# ...

def test_foo():
    p = pytest.tmpdir()
```

With error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tmpdir'

Doing `from pytest import tmpdir` fails with:

> ImportError: cannot import name tmpdir

Comment: The documentation also lists some examples. Does `def test_foo(tmpdir):` work for you?

Comment: The [documentation](http://pytest.org/latest/tmpdir.html) illustrates how to use it, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20545394/1832539) SO post also has an example. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Use `tmp_path` instead of `tmpdir`. `tmp_path` is a [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)/[pathlib2.Path](https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/). `tmpdir` is a [py.path](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html) (Actually [LocalPath](https://py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/path.html#py._path.local.LocalPath)), which has offered syntax very similar to pathlib.Path. See [pytest issue](https://github.com/omarkohl/pytest-datafiles/issues/7).

Usage of py.path is no longer recommended by the developers.

Syntax is similar, eg:

```
def test_something_else(tmp_path):
    #create a file "myfile" in "mydir" in temp directory
    f1 = tmp_path / "mydir/myfile"
    f1.parent.mkdir() #create a directory "mydir" in temp folder (which is the parent directory of "myfile"
    f1.touch() #create a file "myfile" in "mydir"


    #write to file as normal 
    f1.write_text("text to myfile")

    assert f1.read_text() == "text to myfile"
```

**ORIGINAL:** I looked into it an also found the behaviour peculiar, and I summarize what I learned below, for others who don't find it so intuitive.

`tmpdir` is a predefined fixture in pytest similar to how `setup` is defined here:

```
import pytest

class TestSetup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 4

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    return TestSetup()

def test_something(setup)
    assert setup.x == 4
```

Thus `tmpdir` is a fixed name defined in `pytest` which is passed on to your testfunction if you have it as an argument name.

Example usage:

```
def test_something_else(tmpdir):
    #create a file handle for "myfile" in "mydir" in temp folder
    f1 = tmpdir.mkdir("mydir").join("myfile")

    #create a file handle for "myfile" in temp folder
    f2 = tmpdir.join("myfile")

    #write to file as normal (this is what actually creates the file)
    f1.write("text to myfile")

    assert f1.read() == "text to myfile"
```

This works when you run it using pytest, eg running `py.test test_foo.py` in the terminal. The file generated in this way has read and write access, and can be viewed later in your systems temporary folder (for me this was `/tmp/pytest-of-myfolder/pytest-1/test_create_file0`)

Comment: +1 for pointing out `tmpdir` / `tmp_path` difference. I was getting some weird errors because I thought `tmpdir` was already a pathlib.Path

Comment: `tmp_path.mkdir("mydir")` does not work for me. I am getting `TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)`. I had to create a directory object first, and then `mkdir()` it. or use `os.mkdir(tmp_path /  "mydir")`. (linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-6.2.2)

Comment: @Kuchara Well spotted. You are of course right. I have edited the answer.

Comment: what is tmp_path supposed to equal to in your update code @M.T? Should we replace it with a string of the directory in which we want to create temp files?

Comment: @lightbox142 the value of `tmp_path` will be a randomly generated temporary directory of type `pathlib.Path`. You do not have to replace it, pytest will detect the argument name (as pytest has a fixture with that specific name, the same way the `setup`argument is passed in the example above) and fill in the argument before the test is run.

Comment: shouldn't it be `f1.open().read()` instead of `f1.read()`?

Comment: @Jonas You are right, well spotted. I will correct it

Answer (score 14):

You just have to pass the tmpdir as a function parameter as it is a py.test fixture.

```
def test_foo(tmpdir):
    # do things with tmpdir
```