# Pytest Fizzbuzz code

Tags: python, pytest

I have this fizzbuzz code but as a pytest beginner I'm struggling to work out how to test it:

```
def fizzbuzz(nn): 
    for num in range(1,nn+1):
        if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
            print "FizzBuzz"
        elif num % 3 == 0:
            print "Fizz"
        elif num % 5 == 0:
            print "Buzz"
        else:
            print  num
```

I want to test the fizzbuzz(3) =='Fizz' and fizzbuzz(7)== 7
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: `assert fizzbuzz(3) == 'Fizz'`.....?

Comment: you can write [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) in Python for this

Comment: have you read documentation of pytest https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/ have you tried anything?

Comment: @depperm would that work when the function is `print`-ing?

Comment: @depperm That does not work. In fact that's what I already have

Comment: that isn't what you show, so either `return` instead of `print` or look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/20507601/3462319

Comment: or on the documentation page https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, testing is a lot easier if you consider how to test your code while writing it. In this case, you can make testing easier by allowing output to go somewhere other than `stdout`.

from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

```
def fizzbuzz(nn, out=sys.stdout): 
    for num in range(1,nn+1):
        if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
            out.write("FizzBuzz\n")
        elif num % 3 == 0:
            out.write("Fizz\n")
        elif num % 5 == 0:
            out.write("Buzz\n")
        else:
            out.write("{}\n".format(num))

def test_three():
    out = StringIO()
    fizzbuzz(3, out)
    assert out.getvalue() == "1\n2\nFizz\n"

def test_seven():
    out = StringIO()
    fizzbuzz(7, out)
    assert out.getvalue() == "1\n2\nFizz\n4\nBuzz\nFizz\n7\n"
```

`fizzbuzz(3)` should not produce *only* Fizz. If you want to test the output for individual values, now you need to refactor. For example, you might choose to write your code like this:

```
import sys

def fizzbuzz_num(num, out=sys.stdout): 
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        return "FizzBuzz"
    elif num % 3 == 0:
        return "Fizz"
    elif num % 5 == 0:
        return "Buzz"
    else:
        return str(num)

def fizzbuzz(nn, out=sys.stdout): 
    for num in range(1,nn+1):
        out.write(fizzbuzz_num(num) + "\n")

def test_three():
    assert fizzbuzz_num(3) == "Fizz"

def test_seven():
    assert fizzbuzz_num(7) == "7"
```

Probably overkill for such a simple chunk of code, but modularization really helps when it comes to testing.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was struggling with. I appreciate your help. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that your test files and test functions must start (or end, I believe) with the word "test" if you want the `pytest` runner to pick it up automatically. You'll also need to refactor your function to `return` the answer instead of printing it. If you really want to print the items, you can just call `print fizzbuzz(3)` instead of calling `fizzbuzz(3)`. But for testing, you're going to want to `return` the value. You don't have to spend time testing python's `print` function: it works just fine.

Assuming you have pytest installed correctly, you can invoke it from the commandline like this:

```
python -m pytest test_fizz_buzz.py
```

with a test_fizz_buzz.py file that looks like:

```
def test_fizz_buzz():
    assert fizzbuzz(3) == "Fizz"

def test_fizz_buzz():
    assert fizzbuzz(7) == 7
```

You should see output (something) like this:

```
 python -m pytest test_fizz_buzz.py
=============================================== test session starts ===============================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-2.9.2, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1
rootdir: /home/messersmithm, inifile:
collected 2 items

test_fizz_buzz.py ..

============================================ 2 passed in 0.01 seconds =============================================
```