# How to test a console print with pytest and python?

Tags: python-2.7, unit-testing, pytest

I would like to test the print of a function with unitest on python 2.7 :

Example:

```
def load_parse_xml(data_file):
    if os.path.isfile(data_file):
        print "Parsing..."
        data_parse = ET.ElementTree(file=data_file)
        return data_parse.getroot()
    else:
        print data_file + " --> File not exist"
```

In the example I want to test that we have "Parsing ..." in the console

here is my test:

```
def test_load_parse_xml(self):
    data_file = os.getcwd() + "/xml_tests/xmltest.xml"
    load_parse_xml(data_file)
    .......
```

But then I don't know how to test what is written "Parsing ..." in the console. I am blocked!

I just want to test if we have the same message in the console as "Parsing ..."

Comment: I suppose the `print` function is well tested, focus on testing your logic.

Comment: I just want to test if we have the same message in the console as "Parsing ..."

Comment: You should test your code, not Python standard library.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing a pytest function for checking the output on console (stdout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20507601/writing-a-pytest-function-for-checking-the-output-on-console-stdout)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `capsys` from pytest.

See also: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/capture.html#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function

You could do something like this:

```
def test_test(capsys):
    print("Your print out from load_parse_xml")
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out.strip() == "Your print out from load_parse_xml"
```